# Вк. Проблема с отправкой сообщений от лица группы в беседу

Tags: vkontakte-api

Не могу через вк апи отправить сообщение, пока что учусь, поэтому использую ссылки.

Ссылка:

> [https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?chat_id=(номер_беседы)&random_id=(айди_сообщения)&access_token=(тут_токен_группы)&message=(любое_сообщение)&v=5.103](https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?chat_id=(%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B)&random_id=(%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)&access_token=(%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B)&message=(%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)&v=5.103)

В ответ получаю:

> {"error":{"error_code":10,"error_msg":"Internal server error"

Проверил код `10`:

> Произошла внутренняя ошибка сервера. Попробуйте повторить запрос позже.

Вот думаю, может что-то не указал или не правильно написал, дабы 2 день простои с их "серверами".

Собственно в чём есть не уверенность: думаю группа должна писать не через параметр `chat_id`.

Comment: Возможно, некорректный `chat_id`.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что сообщество имеет права администратора в беседе?